# How to define large set of properties of a node without having to type them all?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I have imported a csv file into neo4j. I have been trying to define a large number of properties (all the columns) for each node. How can i do that without having to type in each name?

I have been trying this:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
load csv WITH headers from "file:///frozen_catalog.csv" AS line

//Creating nodes for each product id with its properties
CREATE (product:product{id : line.`o_prd`,
Gross_Price_Average: TOINT(line.`Gross_Price_Average`),
O_PRD_SPG: TOINT(line.`O_PRD_SPG`)});
```

Comment: Please edit your description so we can see your import, or at least a representative version of your import. We can't offer advice if we don't have a good understanding of what you've tried.

Comment: Actually, I am trying to implement a cosine similarity for content based filtering recommendation. I have taken a dataset which contains 415 unique products as rows and then 77 columns which I intend to use as the properties of the product nodes. Now, I have following queries:      1. do I need to write down the names of all individual columns and then convert them to int/float manually ? 2. How do i convert the categorical variables into dummy variables as I need to calculate dot products later, how do i do that in neo4j?

Answer (score 1):

You can adding properties from maps. For example:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "http://data.neo4j.com/northwind/products.csv" AS row
MERGE (P:Product {productID: row.productID})
SET P += row
```

http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/set/#set-adding-properties-from-maps

Comment: Thanks for directing me to this link. But according to the manual, I still will have to write down names of all the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

The LOAD CSV command cannot perform automatic type conversion to ints on certain fields, that must be done explicitly (though you can avoid having to explicitly mention all other fields by using the [map projection](https://neo4j.com/blog/cypher-graphql-neo4j-3-1-preview/) feature to transform your line data before setting it via stdob--'s suggestion).

You may want to take a look at Neo4j's [import tool](http://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/3.1/tutorial/import-tool/), as this will allow you to specify field type in headers, which should perform type conversion for you.

That said, 77 columns is a lot of data to all store on individual nodes. You may want to take another look at your data and figure out if some of those properties would be better modeled as nodes with their own label with relationships to your product nodes. You mentioned some of these were categorical properties. Categories are well suited to be modeled separately as nodes instead of as properties, and maybe some of your other properties would work better as nodes as well.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion :)